# Woocommerce : Creating Preorder related Order statuses - Duplicate coding in Woocommerce to have 2 new statuses?

Tags: woocommerce, status

Preorder scenario.

Default payment now for all items - Instock or Preorder : BACS

I'm trying to add 2 new order status.

1) Preorder Pending With Onhold email template - rename text Onhold to PO Pending.

- Triggered automatically just like the Onhold status.

But only when customer places order for preorder items - differentiate by Preorder stock status.

2) Preorder Paid With Processing email template, text renamed from Processing to PO paid.
* Manual triggered in Order management

If payment is VIA Credit card, then the earlier Pending status can skip. 
- ONLY BACS payment requires PO Pending.

Edit 1 : Please see below for my first attempt -  For the simpler Preorder Paid / Processing

Status is created successfully, and it triggered the Processing Email, but it didn't change the Heading nor the Subject line

```html
// register a custom post status 'preorder-paid' for Orders
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_post_status', 20 );
function register_custom_post_status() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-preorder-paid', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Preorder Paid', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Preorder Paid <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Preorder Paid <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );
}

// Adding custom status 'preorder-paid' to order edit pages dropdown
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'custom_wc_order_statuses', 20, 1 );
function custom_wc_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $order_statuses['wc-preorder-paid'] = _x( 'Preorder Paid', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
    return $order_statuses;
}

// Adding custom status 'preorder-paid' to admin order list bulk dropdown
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order', 20, 1 );
function custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order( $actions ) {
    $actions['mark_preorder-paid'] = __( 'Mark Preorder Paid', 'woocommerce' );
    return $actions;
}

// Adding action for 'preorder-paid'
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'custom_email_actions', 20, 1 );
function custom_email_actions( $action ) {
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-preorder-paid';
    return $actions;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-preorder-paid', array( WC(), 'send_transactional_email' ), 10, 1 );

// Sending an email notification when order get 'preorder-paid' status
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_preorder-paid', 'backorder_status_custom_notification', 20, 2);
function backorder_status_custom_notification( $order_id, $order ) {
    // HERE below your settings
    $heading   = __('Your Preorder Paid order','woocommerce');
    $subject   = '[{site_title}] Preorder Paid order ({order_number}) - {order_date}';

    // Getting all WC_emails objects
    $mailer = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();

    // Customizing Heading and subject In the WC_email processing Order object
    $mailer['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->heading = $heading;
    $mailer['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->subject = $subject;

    // Sending the customized email
 $mailer['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
}
```

Results : No Custom Heading & Subject.  Somehow it wasn't what I expected it to be.

** Would have preferred the follow :

Default Subject :   Your Order : AS-2020-38 is Processing now.
Changed Subject :   Your Preorder : AS-2020-38 is Processing now.

Default Heading : Thank you for your Order!
Changed Heading : Thank you for your Preorder!

And change the text within :

Default Text -- Just to let you know — we've received your order #AS-2020-38, and it is now being processed
Change to -- Just to let you know — we've received your preorder #AS-2020-38, and it is now being processed

Was following Skyverge's article halfway on how to create plugin for this but got lost halfway as his usage scenario = Expedited Shipping. https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/

Edit 2 :

Have another thinking, perhaps it would have been better if I can create a New Custom Order Status based on the On-hold and the Processing -- just change the text "Order" to "Preorder", and have it programmed in the backend like the rest of the default order status?

Is that even remotely possible? I would like to try that.
[image: Default Order Statuses - Emails Tab]

Comment: Just updated to input my first effort..  ...   :).. Disappointing it didn't  at least give me the Custom Heading and Subject line I wanted.  Much less trying to change abit of the text within the email.

Comment: Edited to include new thinking (duplicate statuses in the Email tab) while I try the functions.php coding again to see if I can make new subject and headings appear.

Comment: Seems there's a problem with the bottom half of the coding for the Email sending.  Am I missing something? New WC 4.0+ has revised coding? Can't get the Custonm Heading & Subject to work...